# Issue in a custom layout?

Tags: html, css, web, layout, grid

I have created a news section in the website. Each row contains 4 news cards. Somehow it is not behaving as it should. So can you help me to solve this issue.

Website Link: http://www.shmgroup.com/news.php

[image: Check the image]

I am not able to share the code. Please inspect it.

Comment: `<div class="clearfix"></div>` why are these in the dom ? they are breaking the flow

Comment: you need to use '.news-boxes div[class^="col-"], div[class*=" col-"]{min-height: 490px;}'  or remove <div class="clearfix"></div>

Comment: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) - no, please can you create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem in the question.  Also *it is not behaving as it should* doesn't really explain what the problem is

Comment: It's not clear the issue you faced, it's not clear what are you asking, I suggest to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: _“I am not able to share the code.”_ - then your question does not really belong here in the first place. Looking at your past questions, this seems to be a general MO of yours - link to some site, no code. Please handle this differently on your future questions. This is supposed to be a Q&A site, but if future readers do not even find the situation you described any more on the site you referred to (because you fixed the issue in the mean time), then this question is likely going to be rather worthless to them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the varying height of the image and the text content. I have updated the site with the below CSS changes. 
* Added fixed height to the image instead of width and aligned it in the center.
* Added 3 line clipping to the text description and added a min height.

```
.news-thumbnail img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline;
}

.news-thumbnail {
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.news-excert p {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove div with class clearfix and add fix height to element

```
.news-post-container {
    min-height: 500px; // example
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue arise because your news cards are not in a same height. You can add min-height for news-post-container class.

```
.news-post-container {
    min-height: 450px;
}
```

Remove clearfix classes.

Hope now news page will work properly.

[remove clearfix classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1LcA.png)